# Amazon Athena: Column cannot be resolved or requester is not authorized to access requested resources

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am new to Athena, but running a simple query on my data. The following query works:

```sql
SELECT 
    date_diff('hour',Cast('{sdate}' as timestamp),log_time) as hours_since_launch,
    COUNT(ip) visits
FROM participant_metadata 
WHERE instance_id = '{iid}' 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

However, I would like to filter the results based on `hours_since_launch`. If I try:

```sql
SELECT 
    date_diff('hour',Cast('{sdate}' as timestamp),log_time) as hours_since_launch,
    COUNT(ip) visits
FROM participant_metadata 
WHERE instance_id = '{iid}' 
GROUP BY 1
HAVING hours_since_launch > 4
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

I get the following error:

```
Column 'hours_since_launch' cannot be resolved or requester is not authorized to access requested resources
```

What gives?

Comment: The HAVING clause is processed _before_ the column alias is created.

Answer (score 1):

many databases don't support aliases in HAVING so you can repeat it or make a CTE

```
SELECT 
    date_diff('hour',Cast('{sdate}' as timestamp),log_time) as hours_since_launch,
    COUNT(ip) visits
FROM participant_metadata 
WHERE instance_id = '{iid}' 
GROUP BY 1
HAVING date_diff('hour',Cast('{sdate}' as timestamp),log_time) > 4
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

or

```
WITH CTE AS (    SELECT 
        date_diff('hour',Cast('{sdate}' as timestamp),log_time) as hours_since_launch,
        COUNT(ip) visits
    FROM participant_metadata 
    WHERE instance_id = '{iid}' 
    GROUP BY 1
    )
    SELECT 
        hours_since_launch,
        visits
    FROM CTE WHERE hours_since_launch > 4
    ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```